# Pouring honey into a hot beverage

Tags: food, kashrut-kosher, halacha-theory, meat-and-milk, honey

Can pouring honey into a hot beverage, such as tea, create a Kashruth concern?

In particular, if you pour honey into hot tea with milk, can you later use the same bottle of honey to add honey to a hot meat dish?

Comment: Why honey,and not salt or pepper,zeiah doesn't discriminate

Comment: @sam I think he's thinking that honey is thick enough to make nitzok more of a chibbur.

Comment: @sethj , see Chachmas Adom klal 48:14

Comment: I have asked two prominent Rabbonim in Yerushalayim this question (but with ketchup, not honey) and they both told me there was no issue. Perhaps their reasoning is based on the Bach who holds that there is no issue of zeiah except in a very enclosed area, but I can't say for sure because I didn't ask them for their reasoning.